# Lazy loaded color variables is not defined in Tailwind CSS, in Chrome DevTools

Tags: css, tailwind-css, qwik

Its [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qwik-starter-deuohs), color variable not loaded

I'm trying to lazily load some CSS variables (mostly colors) to be used by Tailwind CSS.

This is part of my `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                custom: {
                    color1: 'var(--color-1)'
                }
            },
```

And this is the `colors.css` file that is loaded when page loads in production. It's not part of the build:

```
:root {
    --color-1: #ff0000;
}
```

And when I run my project, I can see that `colors.css` is loaded, and I can see that the HTML element has these styles applied to them (via Tailwind's compiled styles):

```
#some-element {
    background-color: var(--color-1) !important;
}
```

Yet when I hover over `var(--color-1)` the Chrome DevTools tells me that the variable is not defined.

What should I do?